# Which 1 or 2 ATX PSUs for Asus dominus extreme motherboard?

Tags: motherboard

For a build with a Xeon 3275, Asus dominus extreme, and 4 Nvidia Titan RTX; Should I take 1600W PSU or two 1000W PSUs ?
There is a dual 24-pin on the motherboard: is it mandatory ? for which usage is it ?